# Kubuntu 16.04 > System freeze when connecting from wifi to a wired utp connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, kubuntu, network-manager

I have a DELL XPS-13-9350

Every time my laptop was connected to a wifi. And i connect it to a wired connection. The system freezes, the screen does not update anymore. And keyboard or mouse do not work anymore. After a reboot the wired connection works fine.

I have updated to the newest kernel:

```
$ uname -r
4.8.12-040812-generic
```

But the issue is still the same.

Here some info of the Ethernet interface:

```
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enx00e04c6802d1
   serial: 00:e0:4c:68:02:d1
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.6 duplex=full ip=192.168.178.45 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Do i need to provide more information?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bios update did the trick. Every runs smooth after that.

Edit:
I installed: XPS_9350_1.4.10.exe. I'm not sure what my previous version was. But it came with the xps 9350 when i got it in november 2015.

Thx for the tips, Elder Geek.

Comment: Expanding this answer to include the BIOS versions you updated from and to would make this answer useful.

Comment: I installed: XPS_9350_1.4.10.exe now. I see there is even a newer version available: XPS_9350_1.4.12.exe. I'm not sure what my previous version was. But came with the xps 9350 when i got it in november 2015.

Comment: You might [edit] that valuable information into your post as comments can be deleted for numerous reasons here and it would be unfortunate if it was lost.